# Problems with OpenVPN installation on Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, openvpn

When I was trying to install OpenVPN, i received the next message:

> OpenVPN Connect Setup Wizard ended prematurely. OpenVPN Connect Setup
> Wizard ended prematurely because of an error. Your system has not been
> modified. To install this program at a later time, run Setup Wizard
> again. Click the Finish button to exit Setup Wizard.

[image]

I have Windows 10 with 64 bits OS.

I tried to install this [version of program](https://openvpn.net/downloads/openvpn-connect-v3-windows.msi).

Why is this happening?

Comment: Chances are that you have a corrupt registry key somewhere in there pertaining to the virtual network adapter.  Cisco Any-Connect also has this problem sometimes.  Debugging MSI files is a chore and there is little chance that someone here would be able to *guess* why it is failing without doing that.  I myself would do a repair re-install of windows ***keeping everything*** before anything else.

Comment: In the end, only reinstalling the operating system did it work.